# Como crear una lista de consultas mysql, en tiempo real jquery y mostrarlo en una vista

Tags: mysql, jquery, ajax, laravel

Tengo este código, en el cual hago mi consulta por `Ajax` en **Laravel 5.7**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#caja_consulta').on('keyup',function(){
    $value=$(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url : "{{route('searchpackage')}}",
        data:{'caja_consulta':$value},
        success:function(data){
            $('tbody').append(data); // En esta parte quiero imprimir mi consulta el cual es un único registro en mi BD, pero por alguna razón lo repite.
            $('#caja_consulta').val('');
        }
    });
 });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
</script>
```

Como pueden observar el código de Jquery hace que una vez que se coloca texto en el input lo borra (esto debido a que se lee con una maquina de lectura de código de barras), busca el id en la tabla y devuelve todo el registro.

Pero en esta parte (Append) quiero imprimir mi consulta el cual es un único registro en mi BD, pero por alguna razón lo repite.

Esta es una pantalla del como se muestra, pero como mencione solo debería ser una vez no 2.
[image: Funcionalidad del sistema]

Es la mejor solución que encontré, podrían darme alguna otra opción.

De antemano se los agradezco.

Este es el codigo del controlador que lanza la consulta a la BD.

```
public function searchpackage(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax()){

        $output="";

        $caja_consulta = $request->caja_consulta;
        $consulta = detailBults::where("idDetalle",$caja_consulta)->take(1)->get(); 

        if($consulta){
            foreach($consulta as $cons){
                $output='<tr>'.
                '<td>'.$cons->idDetalle.'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$cons->mono.'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$cons->Line.'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$cons->PN.'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$cons->qtyord.'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$cons->PCSPKG.'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$cons->Operation.'</td>'.
                '<td>'.$cons->tiempo.' min</td>'.
                '</tr>';
            }
            return ($output);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: ya intentaste hacer `$('tbody').empty();` antes del `append`

Comment: Te refieres a hacer esto: $('tbody').empty().append(data); o en 2 lineas distintas

Comment: Si no me equivoco de las dos formas deberia de funcionar, solo debes probar,

Comment: @JesusAlejandroNuñezJaimez tiene pinta de que tu servidor la esta devolviendo 2 veces pero sin ese código no te lo podemos decir exacto.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa creo no quiere limpiar el tbody s noi añadir a la tabla un registro cada vez pero le esta añadiendo 2 cada vez

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa ya probe y es como si hiciera $('tbody').html(data), es decir reemplaza cada que busco un nuevo registro pero no lo mantiene en pantalla.

Comment: @JDev si es asi, entonces es como dices: la data viene repetida del mismo servidor, pense a que se referia que cada vez que hace una busqueda se duplicaba, en otras palabras iba acumulando la data.

Comment: @JesusAlejandroNuñezJaimez no habia visto que lanzabas el evento cada vez que levantas el dedo de una tecla. Aparte de que esto hace llamadas inncesarias es probable que si haces intro al final te devuelva 2 veces la misma tupla.

Comment: @JDev te refieres al codigo que realiza la consulta a la BD??

Comment: @JesusAlejandroNuñezJaimez si, al que llama jquery.

Comment: Listo es mi codigo del controlador y el Jquery

Comment: Visto el controlador parece que por alguna razon la llamada ajax se realiza 2 veces. ¿Tienes que lanzar el evento obligatoriamente con keyup o puede ser con el boton de 'Agregar' ?

Comment: Estoy intentado hacerlo con click, pero no me manda nada, quizas estoy teniendo mal mi sintaxis.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por su ayuda uno de los comentarios tenia razon, decidi hacerlo con click en lugar de keyup y funciono correctamente.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(inicializarElementos);

function inicializarElementos(){
    $("#button").click(clickElemento);
}

function clickElemento(){
    var texto = $("#caja_consulta").val();


 $value=texto;

 $.ajax({

 type : 'get',

 url : "{{URL::to('searchpackage')}}",

 data:{'caja_consulta':$value},

 success:function(data){
            $('tbody').append(data);
              $('#caja_consulta').val('');



 }

 });
 }


</script>
```